# How to create both a POST and GET version of the same express endpoint?

Tags: node.js, express

I have 2 endpoints that are essentially identical, the only difference is that one of them is a GET request with query params, and the other is a POST request with body params.

```
app.get('/sameEndpoint', (req, res) => {
    let param1 = req.query.param1;
    let param2 = req.query.param2;

    res.send(param1 + param2);
}

app.post('/sameEndpoint', (req, res) => {
    let param1 = req.body.param1;
    let param2 = req.body.param2;

    res.send(param1 + param2);
}
```

I would like to refactor this somehow so that all changes are made in only one place. It may seem like a dumb question, but I'm not sure if there is a simple solution to this problem or not.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can create a utility function for this and utilize computed properties.

```
const myEndPointFunc = property => {
     let param1 = req[property].param1;
     let param2 = req[property].param2;
     res.send(param1 + param2);
};


app.get('/sameEndpoint', (req, res) => myEndPointFunc("query"));
app.post('/sameEndpoint', (req, res) => myEndPointFunc("body"));
```

Comment: Thanks! I hadn't thought of this approach!

Answer (score 0):

```
app.all('/sameEndpoint', function (req, res, next) {
  commonCode();
})
```